# Force use of scientific style for basemap colorbar labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

String formatting can by used to specify scientific notation for matplotlib.basemap colorbar labels:

```
cb = m.colorbar(cs, ax=ax1, format='%.4e')
```

But then each label is scientifically notated with the base.

If numbers are large enough, the colobar automatically reduces them to scientific notation, placing the base (i.e. `x10^n`) at the top of the color bar, leaving only the coefficient numbers as labels.

You can do this with a standard axis with the following:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))
```

Is there an equivalent method for matplotlib.basemap colorbars, or perhaps a standard matplotlib colorbar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no one-line method, but you can do this by updating the colorbar's `formatter` and then calling `colorbar.update_ticks()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.random.random((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(z)
cb = fig.colorbar(im)

cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
cb.update_ticks()

plt.show()
```

[image]

The reason for the slightly odd way of doing things is that a colorbar actually has statically assigned ticks and ticklabels.  The colorbar's axes (`colorbar.ax`) actually always ranges between 0 and 1.  (Therefore, altering `colorbar.ax.yaxis.formatter` doesn't do anything useful.) The tick positions and labels are calculated from `colorbar.locator` and `colorbar.formatter` and are assigned when the colorbar is created.  Therefore, if you need precise control over a colorbar's ticks/ticklables, you need to explicitly call `colorbar.update_ticks()` after customizing how the ticks are displayed.  The colorbar's convenience functions do this for you behind the scenes, but as far as I know, what you want can't be done through another method.

Comment: Excellent. That would have certainly taken me far too long to figure out. So I presume this would also work for a `basemap` colorbar? Thanks Joe.

Comment: Happy to help! It should work exactly the same for a `basemap` colorbar. I don't think `basemap` axes change the colorbar in any way, but I could be wrong about that.