# Colorbar scientific notation offset

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

When plotting a colorbar, the top label (I guess this would be called the offset) is mis-centered. This didn't use to happen, I have examples of old code where it was centered above the colorbar, but I have no clue what has changed.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.random.random((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(z)
cb = fig.colorbar(im)

cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
cb.update_ticks()

plt.show()
```

Gives this:

[image: Offset colorbar notation]

As an example of how it used to look (taken from one of my old papers, so
different data etc.)

[image: Proper colorbar notation]

Using the most recent anaconda python 2.7, on MacOSX, mpl version 1.5.0

Edit: I should also note, tight_layout() does not improve this either, though it is missing from the working example.

Comment: More direct comparison in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25370358/707650).

Comment: I guess this figure is the one reason why [`jet`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/875) should not be removed as colormap, and still has its uses: I can stare at it endlessly and slowly float away into some form of hyperspace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use `set_offset_position` for the y-axis of the colorbar. Compare:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()                
im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))                    
cb = fig.colorbar(im)     
cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
cb.ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('right')                         
cb.update_ticks()
plt.show()
```

[image]

versus

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10)))
cb = fig.colorbar(im)
cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
cb.ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('left')
cb.update_ticks()
plt.show()
```

[image]

All in all, it simply looks like the default has changed from right to left.

Comment: Wonderful, I'll go with this as the answer since it doesn't require downgrading. Thank you very much! 

Confusing about the left/right though, you have to use left to move the label more toward the right! Weird!

Comment: @ajclarke I think `left` means align the left of the label with the left side of the colorbar, whereas `right` means align the right of the label with the right side of the colorbar

Comment: Yes, it appears to be as tom mentions. Unfortunately, this is one of the parts where the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axis_api.html#matplotlib.axis.YAxis.set_offset_position) is still lacking in matplotlib. Luckily, mpl has tons of examples that serve often better as documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Using your above code and matplotlib version 1.4.3 I get the following plot
[image]

So this may be a version issue.  One possible work around could be to use `cb.ax.text()`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = np.random.random((10,10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(z)
cb = fig.colorbar(im)
cb.ax.text(-0.25, 1, r'$\times$10$^{-1}$', va='bottom', ha='left')

plt.show()
```

This way you have more control over the centring.  The above code gives me the following plot
[image]
Note that I use an `r` at the start of the string so that `$\times$` produces the correct symbol.

Comment: Can confirm, downgrading to 1.4.3 fixes this issue. I can live with using that version.

The only thing I don't understand is why the colorbar in your example doesn't have the offset from plt.colorbar itself. When I do it, the cb.ax.text just plops over the top of the colorbar's default offset label

Comment: I think that's because I deleted the following lines:
`cb.formatter.set_powerlimits((0, 0))` and
`cb.update_ticks()`