# Colorbar offset settings

Tags: python, matplotlib

Following on from this question: [Matplotlib Colorbar scientific notation offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34039396/matplotlib-colorbar-scientific-notation-offset)

Is it possible to set this permenantly, so mpl behaves this way all the time. It's really annoying to go back through all my scripts and adjust using

```
cb.ax.yaxis.set_offset_position('left')                         
cb.update_ticks()
```

I looked in rcParams, but nothing there seems to work.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't look like there is anything obvious is rcParams or the matplotlibrc file.

Comment: What version of MPL are you using?  My axes default to `yaxis.offset_text_position = u'left'`.  I'm using 1.5.0.

Comment: according to the [source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/8379d78c8aa073e3cdf7067a1da38f24531e3174/lib/matplotlib/axis.py#L2044), the default appears to be `left`

Comment: I'm using 1.5.0 as well, though mine appears (as in the linked question) to have changed default from left to right.